# Is it possible to resolve imported module path at compile time in Webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, webpack, webpack-5

I want to create build that will, based on env variable, include just specific components in the bundle.

For example when I import component like this:

```
import Module1 from '@/components/Module1'
```

I want the path to actually be converted so that imports looks like this:

```
import Module1 from '@/components/brands/' + process.env.APP_BRAND + 'Module1'
```

Now I don't want to do this for all imports, just for certain ones (eg. modules that have branded version), so maybe I'd like to prefix import path with something like `!brand!` which will be indicator to apply path transform.
So above logic should executed only for import paths such as:

```
import Module1 from '!brand!@/components/Module1'
```

And if `process.env.APP_BRAND` is falsy then I just want to stick to the original import (eg. just remove `!brand!` prefix from the path).

So the important aspect is that I want this to be done at build time so that Webpack can statically analyze modules and create optimized build. Is this possible to do? I suppose I need to somehow add this path transformation logic but how should I do that? Should I create a loader, plugin or is there an existing solution?

I am using Webpack 5.

Answer (score 2):

Webpack provides a module **resolve** functionality that you can use here. Read the [docs here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/). As an example, in your case, you can do this:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@/components/Module1': path.join(
        __dirname,
        process.env.APP_BRAND
          ? '@/components/brands/' + process.env.APP_BRAND + 'Module1'
          : '@/components/Module1')
    }
  },
};
```

Note that, here you would pass environment variable to your Webpack process (aka Node.js process) and make decision accordingly. Also, your resolve module must be **absolute path**.